# Debug Macro strange behaviour

Tags: c, debugging, compilation

I have a file as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEBUG

int main(void) {

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("We are in debug mode");
#endif

}
```

I was told to use ifdef and endif (for this).
My problem occurs when I compile this, using a makefile(Which I'm not allowed to edit). What happens is the print statement (Debug one) prints, which shouldn't because I'm not in DEBUG mode. I tried to use this command (On Ubuntu 14.04)

`make -DEBUG`

But that did something completely different, and the output file, prints the ifdef statement, despite not being in DEBUG mode.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove #define from C file. Then use makefile as makefile will enable/disable the preprocessor "DEBUG".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly defining DEBUG in your source file

```
#define DEBUG
```

Remove that line so that you are not overriding any definition from your build environment.

Comment: My Professor told me to do this? Not sure if I misinterpreted it, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly defining `DEBUG` in your source file, (with `#define DEBUG`), so you will *always* be in debug mode, regardless of how you build things.

Remove the `#define DEBUG` it will be in non-debug mode, unless debug is set on compile command line.

Use the command `make CPPFLAGS=-DDEBUG` to build with a makefile and add the `-DDEBUG` argument to the preprocessor flags so as to build in debug mode (note the two `D`s)

Comment: Iwas told to use "make -DEBUG", so do I still have to remove the "define DEBUG"?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

#ifdef DEBUG
   printf("We are in debug mode");
#endif

return 0;
}
```

when debug is needed do this

```
 gcc src.c -DDEBUG
```

-D option is used for run time macro

Also note 
ifdef check only for definition, it does not checks the value to be true or false

```
------------------------
#define DEBUG 0
if (DEBUG)
  will not enter here

#ifdef DEBUG
  will enter here
$endif
------------------------

#define debug 0
int main()
{

if (debug) {
   printf("Hello, World!2\n");
}

#ifdef debug
   printf("Hello, World!3\n");
#endif

return 0;
}
-----------------------------------
output:
Hello, World!3
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.